# Multiplayer HTML5, Node.js, Socket.IO

Tags: html, node.js, canvas, socket.io

I trying create simple Multi-player with HTML5 Canvas, JavaScript(too using John Resig simple Inheritance library) and Node.js with Socket.IO.
My client code:

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById('game');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var socket  = new io.Socket('127.0.0.1', {port: 8080});

var player = null;

var UP    = 'UP',
    LEFT  = 'LEFT',
    DOWN  = 'DOWN',
    RIGHT = 'RIGHT';

socket.connect();

socket.on('connect', function() {socket.send();
    console.log('Connected!');
    player = new Player(50, 50);
});

socket.on('message', function(msg) {
    if(msg == 'UP') {
        player.moveUP();
    } else if(msg == 'LEFT') {
        player.moveLEFT();
    } else if(msg == 'DOWN') {
        player.moveDOWN();
    } else if(msg == 'RIGHT') {
        player.moveRIGHT();
    } else {

    }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Disconnected!');
});

var Player = Class.extend({
    init : function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    },
    setX : function(x){
        this.x = x;
    },
    getX : function(){
        return this.x;
    },
    setY : function(y){
        this.y = y;
    },
    getY : function(){
        return this.y;
    },
    draw : function(){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 350, 150);
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 15, 15);
    },
    move : function() {
        this.x += 1;
        this.y += 1;
    },
    moveUP : function() {
        this.y--;
    },
    moveLEFT : function() {
        this.x--;
    },
    moveDOWN : function() {
        this.y++;
    },
    moveRIGHT : function() {
        this.x++;
    }
});

function checkKeyCode(event) {
    var keyCode;
    if(event == null) {
        keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
        keyCode = event.keyCode;
    }

    switch(keyCode) {
        case 38: // UP
            player.moveUP();
            socket.send(UP);
        break;
        case 37: // LEFT
            player.moveLEFT();
            socket.send(LEFT);
        break;
        case 40: //DOWN
            player.moveDOWN();
            socket.send(DOWN);
        break;
        case 39: // RIGHT
            player.moveRIGHT();
            socket.send(RIGHT);
        break;
        default:
        break;

    }

}

function update() {
    player.draw();
}

var FPS = 30;
setInterval(function() {
    update();
    player.draw();
}, 1000/FPS);

function init() {
    document.onkeydown = checkKeyCode;
}

init();
```

And server code:

```
var http = require('http'),
io = require('socket.io'),
buffer = new Array(),

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});
server.listen(8080);

var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function(client){

    client.on('message', function(message){
        console.log(message);
        client.broadcast(message);
    })
    client.on('disconnect', function(){

    })

});
```

And when I run two client's I with first client can move second client Rect and with second client move first client rect and something like with third client can move first and second client rect's.

I have question how to create real Multi-Player? something like:
Open three client's and first client get rect1, second rect2 and last rect3. First client only can move rect1, client third can move only rect3.

Maybe anyone have idea? I search in Google but don't find answer.

Sorry for my English language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, check out http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/super-browser-2-turbo-hd-remix-introduction-to-html5-game-development.html

it explains how to use requestAnimationFrame among other things.

Second, the game state should exist on the server and be mirrored on the clients.

When a player clicks down, the client should only send a message.  The server should then send a message to all the clients, including the client that took the action.

Each player should exist as an object on the server.  When a player logs in they should be brought up to date about the status of each player already on the server.

modified client code: http://codr.cc/s/d0154536/js

modified server code: http://codr.cc/s/f96ce1d2/js

Comment: Super browser 2 turbo HD remix introduction to HTML5 game development is awesome!
Thanks for answers!
generalhenry, I try your modeified client/server code but for my don't work.

But thanks for help me to understand Multi-Player!

Comment: I didn't test my modified code so there are likely some bugs, but you get the idea ^_^

Comment: All links are currently dead from this answer.

Comment: the first link in the answer is broken

Answer (score 11):

Glenn Fiedler's [What every programmer needs to know about game networking](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/what-every-programmer-needs-to-know-about-game-networking/) -article is good read for anyone who wants get into game networking. It explains the basics in very high level so that it is adaptable for JS and Socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this question as I have just now, I wanted to add [this link as an example](https://github.com/commanderZiltoid/socketio-authoritative-fps).

I was following the same path as the op several months ago and read every article I could find on the authoritative server model (including the one referenced in the answer by @Epeli), and how to implement it with nodejs/socketio.

The result of my research manifested itself in the github project located at the link provided above (there is also a live demo). Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an open-source multiplayer realtime javascript server (and client library) called [Lance.gg](https://github.com/lance-gg/lance), which provides, as you say,
*a real multiplayer experience*

It handles client-side prediction, step drift, bending, and basic physics.

Disclaimer: I am one of the contributors