# Simple multiplayer game development with socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

**Multuplayer game with socket.io - Make the bigger word from letters**

How need to works my game:

1. user click on stop and then they get a letters to create a bigger word than other player DONE!
2. when user cretate a word then click to"submit" button and send to server and server chose the bigger word... NOT done yet
3. here we must to allow two player game with socket.io

Here is the code for basic ONE player game mod: http://jsfiddle.net/9rtFa/14/

also in game have a real time chat for player to chat beetwen.

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
        // update the list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });
});
```

and index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        socket.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>'+username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
    socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
        });
    });

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            socket.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>USERS</b>
    <div id="users"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```

NOW I need to allow two player game with letters in realtime with socket.io - chat I already have but how to IMPLEMENT socket.io into my game - code I place above from jsfiddle

Please HELP to understand socket.io game development.

I think that must be a good tutorial for understanding socket.io for creating game.
I think that this will be so interesting to many people here...

Comment: why     -1     why ..............

Comment: ok, thanks, but I think that must be interesting to many people to understand with example how socket.io work

Comment: Not a real question, suggest you read the FAQ. As far as what you seem to be asking, game is irrelevant to multi-user client server. Game is content, mechanics are the same, and  Chat server is a classic example...

Comment: how to create a multyplayer version of this; jsfiddle.net/9rtFa/12/ witj realtime connections and users

Comment: maybe its not a good place for this question, I will delete him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very hard to understand, so Im not exactly sure what you are asking for, besides just general advice.

I did a quick search and found this [Multiplayer HTML5, Node.js, Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244230/multiplayer-html5-node-js-socket-io)

Might be helpful?

Comment: I jst want to allow multiplayer gaming for my simple game jsfiddle.net/9rtFa/12/

Comment: You cant just "allow" multiplayer. It will have to be programmed to handle multiplayer interaction.